# WPF WebBrowser Control: What browser does it use?

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

Does the WPF WebBrowser control always use Internet Explorer or does it use the default web browser on the system ?

Regards,
MadSeb

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Internet Explorer, though there are "hacks" posted on the internet which allow you to use a workaround in order to launch any browser you like.

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/cf66e0cd-ab6f-45b8-b230-1d78f26670d2) thread seems to explain one of the possible solutions.

Comment: A bunch of the hacks are explicitly listed and linked-to in the answers to a WPF Browser-related question that I asked a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940944/wpf-browser-is-there-but-invisible

Comment: There is no hack to embed any browser you want in the WebBrowser control... It will always be IE. What you *can* do is to make it open new windows in another browser, rather than IE

Comment: thanks guy for replying ...Internet Explorer is the web browser I want in the WPF WebBrowser control...as I want to display a MHT file ( webarchive ) ..So for me it's crucial that the WPF WebBrowser control **ALWAYS USES** Internet Explorer

Answer (score 12):

> One issue the Web Browser Control has that it’s perpetually stuck in IE 7
>   rendering mode by default. Even though IE 8 and now 9 have
>   significantly upgraded the IE rendering engine to be more CSS and HTML
>   compliant by default the Web Browser control will have none of it. IE
>   9 in particular – with its much improved CSS support and basic HTML 5
>   support is a big improvement and even though the IE control uses some
>   of IE’s internal rendering technology it’s still stuck in the old IE 7
>   rendering by default.
>
> This applies whether you’re using the Web Browser control in a WPF
>   application, a WinForms app, a FoxPro or VB classic application using
>   the ActiveX control. Behind the scenes all these UI platforms use the
>   COM interfaces and so you’re stuck by those same rules.

See this:
Web Browser Control – Specifying the IE Version

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version