# How to Render Internet Explorer 9 in WPF Frame Control

Tags: wpf, html, internet-explorer-9

I have a frame control in a WPF app which has an HTML page as a source. The HTML page uses HTML5 features, mostly for a video.

However I can't seem to get it to work in the frame control. I already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822537/wpf-webbrowser-control-what-browser-does-it-use) here on StackOverflow which points to [this page](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version).

If I'm understanding correctly, the default behaviour for frame controls is to render in IE7 mode which explains why the video doesn't work. I've tried adding the application to the registry as described in the second page I've linked but somehow I'm either doing it wrong or it doesn't work for me.

I've set the name of my application as a DWORD key and the value to 0x00002328 in the registry for both:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

and

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

This at least seems to get the rendered browser into IE9 mode - according to a little script I use to detect the browser. Still no video, though. When I run the same HTML page in an IE9 browser the video displays correctly.

Does anybody have any idea on how to solve this or whether it is solvable at all?

Comment: What exactly have you set in your registry?

Comment: I've updated the original question. It seems that I have to set the key and value in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER branch as well. I played around a bit. But I still can't play the video - althoug the HTML page works in the IE9 browser in general.

Comment: To eliminate any `DOCTYPE` switching issues it's probably worth trying `0x270F` instead, but if that doesn't work then I'm not sure.  You could also try adding an element with `border-radius` style set - that'll only work if the browser is rendering as IE9.

Comment: I did that an strangely enough, the rounded corners work just fine, but the video still doesn't play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone helped solving the issue in the MSDB forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/87e41b0d-145d-4438-958e-c8b3a0a969d3

The important thing seems to be adding this meta information to the html:

```
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=9' />
```

That seems to do the trick.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=unicode' />
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=9' /> 
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
         <video autoplay='autoplay' preload='metadata'>
            <source src='test_video.mp4' type='video/mp4' />
        </video>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```