# WebBrowser does not display content correctly

Tags: wpf, vb.net, webbrowser-control, web-controls

I use vb.net + wpf+ `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` to display web content on a wpf form.

This website "http://manuim.com/laisha/" does not display correctly on the control.

When I checked on IE+Firefox+Chrome - the site display correctly.

Please help

Comment: This references the Wpf Webrowser control, see if it is applicable to your situation though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822537/wpf-webbrowser-control-what-browser-does-it-use

Comment: thanks for the info.
I did not really find anything that I could use...

Answer (score 4):

I just found an article that helped me.

So, if its going to help someone that bumps into my question - here goes:

You can edit the registry and "force" the Web browser control to use a different IE version.

I used value 9999 (decimal) and it helped.

Read this [article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version)