# Embedded Signing with Safari on Mac not working as intended

Tags: docusignapi

I successfully (with much frustration) got our c# embedded signing to work on our site, however,  that was before I tested with Safari on a Mac.  Safari does not allow Third party sites to open in an iframe without already having a cookie for that site stored.  If you either open the site beforehand or allowing all cookies, the document will show embedded.  However, even messing around with that, the redirection after completion is not working.  The please wait popup does not redirect back to my site.  I am looking for any embedded solution that supports mac.

The process works great on windows, but does not work on Safari for Mac and is intermittent with Firefox and Chrome on mac.

I am looking for any non-iFrame embedded solutions that I could implement that should work on all platforms and browsers.

Comment: I want to add here that we are also having issues with the DocuSign embedding signing process. They claim no one is reporting any issues but as I see here, there are at least two individuals reporting otherwise.

Comment: I also had the same problem and what I did was-`added a link to open the recipient window if iframe not working. This link is only visible in safari. Once user clicks on the link it opens docuSign url and next time iframe loads automatically.`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only workaround that I know of is to pop up a new browser window.  I know there is work being done to make it work without cookies, but at this time the new browser window is your only choice.

Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have embedding working in terms of generating a URL token, it's up to you how to access that URL.  We've seen developers write their own programs to view where they have complete control over the iFrame and can do whatever they like with it, and another solution we've seen is to use a web browser control.

[see this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822537/wpf-webbrowser-control-what-browser-does-it-use)