# Docusign embedded signing users reporting a blank applet / iframe

Tags: docusignapi

I have been unable to recreate this locally on any browser versions, but I am getting reports from a client that users are getting to the embedded signing portion of my form and just receiving a "blank window". All reports have, of course, been Internet Explorer related.

It is not a persistent issue, it happens intermittently. I am wondering if this is a known issue, and if other DocuSign users / devs might be seeing or have seen the same issue.

Unfortunately, I haven't got much information myself on these incidents.

This question applies to and is aimed at both DocuSign developers and users. 
**Please do not edit the tags.**

I am wondering if the issue may be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955117/embedded-signing-with-safari-on-mac-not-working-as-intended).

Comment: We would need some more info to go on than this to be able to address/resolve any potential issues.  However I have to say that Embedding is very popular functionality used in the DocuSign API and we don't currently have other reports of this happening...

Comment: Per your tags comment - normal DocuSign users don't use Stack Overflow (most don't even know what it is).  They go through DocuSign support, only relevant tag is DocuSignAPI.  Please remove the generic DocuSign tag - you'll see this is the only question tagged with it...

Comment: That's fine, if someone searches without going to your developer site, they are going to search for docusign, not docusignapi. I'm not sure why you would not want DocuSign tagged on all docusign related posts, but even still it applies because it is a post relative to DocuSign and it's API

Comment: I'll update with information when and if I receive it, my best guess is that there's some sort of race condition or intermittent server communication issues. I've added code that alerts me any time an envelope frame is presented, and I'm going to add code to detect a proper load.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, we have not encountered this issue with our implementation of embedded signing. Our corporate standard browser is IE. We have, however, encountered another issue with embedded signing and IE (versions 9, 10 and 11).  See my post "Missing Draw Link on Adopt Signature Dialog in Embedded Signing Session" (https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bdocusignapi%5d%20embedded).

We have discovered font issues--particularly Calibri--with documents converted to PDF. To fix that the font must be embedded in the PDF or must be installed in an Adobe font directory on the user's machine.