# WebBrowser.Navigate not working in IE11

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

We have a WPF desktop application based on CCF which hosts a angular.js web application.

We need to navigate to a specific URl of the web application by using `WebBrowser.Navigate` method.

But `WebBrowser.Navigate` works perfectly in IE8 and fails in IE11.

Code :

```
    public void NavigateToSpecificUrl(string urlToBeNavigated)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(urlToBeNavigated))
        {
         if (System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                if (this.Browser != null)
                {
                    this.Browser.Navigate(urlToBeNavigated);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                NavigateToUrl objNavigateToUrl = new NavigateToUrl(NavigateToSpecificUrl);
                System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(objNavigateToUrl, urlToBeNavigated);
            }

           }
         }
```

The code when called repeatedly over a certain time works in IE11. Need a uniform method which works both in IE8 and IE11.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3822537/2470362) may help.

Comment: IE version is 6 within the application. Though the installed version of IE is 11. Its not making any difference.