# VS 2015 - WebBrowser control does not reveal alternating table row colors in CSS

Tags: css, vb.net, colors, html-table, webbrowser-control

The following code will employ CSS to write a table with alternating row colors to an html file.  After writing to disk, when directly viewing the html file with e.g. Firefox, Chrome, IE, etc, the alternating row colors are visible.  However, in VS2015, after loading the html file into a WebBrowser1 control, the alternating row colors are not visible.

I have checked other posts on SO and elsewhere, and it is apparent that WebBrowser just wraps IE, and to overcome problems with WebBrowser there are workarounds involving installation of 3rd party open sources. However, what about a straightforward solution for this issue from MS?  This seems like an underdeveloped issue for MS and VS2015, since it implies the current controls bundled with VS2015 have issues with CSS.  Any MS-based solutions for this?

```
Dim sw As New StreamWriter(filename)
sw.WriteLine("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>")
sw.WriteLine("<style type=" & """" & "text/css" & """" & ">")
sw.WriteLine("table.gridtable {")
sw.WriteLine("  font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;")
sw.WriteLine("  font-size:12px;")
sw.WriteLine("  color: #333333;")
sw.WriteLine("  border-width: 1px;")
sw.WriteLine("  border-color: #666666;")
sw.WriteLine("  border-collapse: collapse;")
sw.WriteLine("}")
sw.WriteLine("table.gridtable th {")
sw.WriteLine("  border-width: 1px;")
sw.WriteLine("  padding: 8px;")
sw.WriteLine("  border-style: solid;")
sw.WriteLine("  border-color: #666666;")
sw.WriteLine("  background-color: #dedede;")
sw.WriteLine("}")
sw.WriteLine("table.gridtable tr {")
sw.WriteLine("background-color: #ffffff;")
sw.WriteLine("}")
sw.WriteLine("table.gridtable tr:nth-child(even) {")
sw.WriteLine("background-color: #fdf5e6;")
sw.WriteLine("}")
sw.WriteLine("table.gridtable td {")
sw.WriteLine("  border-width: 1px;")
sw.WriteLine("  padding: 8px;")
sw.WriteLine("  border-style: solid;")
sw.WriteLine("  border-color: #666666;")
sw.WriteLine("}")
sw.WriteLine("</style>")

sw.WriteLine("<table class=" & """" & "gridtable" & """" & " Align=center>")
sw.WriteLine("<tr>")
sw.Write("<th>" & "Output" & "</th>")
sw.Write("<th>" & "Output" & "</th>")
sw.Write("<th>" & "Output" & "</th>")
sw.Write("<th>" & "Output" & "</th>")
sw.WriteLine("</tr>")
sw.WriteLine("<tr>")
sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
sw.WriteLine("</tr>")
sw.WriteLine("<tr>")
sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
sw.WriteLine("</tr>")
sw.WriteLine("<tr>")
sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
sw.WriteLine("</tr>")
sw.WriteLine("<tr>")
sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
sw.WriteLine("<td align=""center""><font color=" & """" & "#000000" & """" & ">Hello</font></td>")
sw.WriteLine("</tr>")
sw.WriteLine("</table>")
sw.WriteLine("</body></html>")
sw.dispose
```

Comment: check out this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822537/wpf-webbrowser-control-what-browser-does-it-use

Comment: and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6abee729-ac0b-47c5-9603-d1b3050618af/webbrowser-not-applying-css-correctly?forum=wpf

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: to help others, I converted a C# solution published at [Configuring the emulation mode of an Internet Explorer WebBrowser control, by Richard James Moss](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/793687/configuring-the-emulation-mode-of-an-internet-expl) into VB.NET.

First add the following imports to an independent Module (not e.g. Form1):

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Security
```

Next, add the following class to the module:

```
Public Class InternetExplorerBrowserEmulation
    Public Enum BrowserEmulationVersion
        [Default] = 0
        Version7 = 7000
        Version8 = 8000
        Version8Standards = 8888
        Version9 = 9000
        Version9Standards = 9999
        Version10 = 10000
        Version10Standards = 10001
        Version11 = 11000
        Version11Edge = 11001
    End Enum
    Private Const BrowserEmulationKey As String = InternetExplorerRootKey & "\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION"
    Public Function GetBrowserEmulationVersion() As BrowserEmulationVersion
        Dim result As BrowserEmulationVersion

        result = BrowserEmulationVersion.Default

        Try
            Dim key As RegistryKey

            key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(BrowserEmulationKey, True)
            If key IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim programName As String
                Dim value As Object

                programName = Path.GetFileName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()(0))
                value = key.GetValue(programName, Nothing)

                If value IsNot Nothing Then
                    result = CType(Convert.ToInt32(value), BrowserEmulationVersion)
                End If
            End If
        Catch e1 As SecurityException
            ' The user does not have the permissions required to read from the registry key.
        Catch e2 As UnauthorizedAccessException
            ' The user does not have the necessary registry rights.
        End Try

        Return result
    End Function

    Public Function IsBrowserEmulationSet() As Boolean
        Return GetBrowserEmulationVersion() <> BrowserEmulationVersion.Default
    End Function

    Public Function SetBrowserEmulationVersion(ByVal browserEmulationVersion As BrowserEmulationVersion) As Boolean
        Dim result As Boolean

        result = False

        Try
            Dim key As RegistryKey

            key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(BrowserEmulationKey, True)

            If key IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim programName As String

                programName = Path.GetFileName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()(0))

                If browserEmulationVersion <> BrowserEmulationVersion.Default Then
                    ' if it's a valid value, update or create the value
                    key.SetValue(programName, CInt(Fix(browserEmulationVersion)), RegistryValueKind.DWord)
                Else
                    ' otherwise, remove the existing value
                    key.DeleteValue(programName, False)
                End If

                result = True
            End If
        Catch e1 As SecurityException
            ' The user does not have the permissions required to read from the registry key.
        Catch e2 As UnauthorizedAccessException
            ' The user does not have the necessary registry rights.
        End Try

        Return result
    End Function

    Public Function SetBrowserEmulationVersion() As Boolean
        Dim ieVersion As Integer
        Dim emulationCode As BrowserEmulationVersion

        ieVersion = GetInternetExplorerMajorVersion()

        If ieVersion >= 11 Then
            emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version11
        Else
            Select Case ieVersion
                Case 10
                    emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version10
                Case 9
                    emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version9
                Case 8
                    emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version8
                Case Else
                    emulationCode = BrowserEmulationVersion.Version7
            End Select
        End If

        Return SetBrowserEmulationVersion(emulationCode)
    End Function

    Private Const InternetExplorerRootKey As String = "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer"

    Public Function GetInternetExplorerMajorVersion() As Integer
        Dim result As Integer = Nothing

        result = 0

        Try
            Dim key As RegistryKey

            key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(InternetExplorerRootKey)

            If key IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim value As Object

                value = If(key.GetValue("svcVersion", Nothing), key.GetValue("Version", Nothing))

                If value IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim version As String
                    Dim separator As Integer

                    version = value.ToString()
                    separator = version.IndexOf("."c)
                    If separator <> -1 Then
                        Integer.TryParse(version.Substring(0, separator), result)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Catch e1 As SecurityException
            ' The user does not have the permissions required to read from the registry key.
        Catch e2 As UnauthorizedAccessException
            ' The user does not have the necessary registry rights.
        End Try

        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```

Finally, in the Form1_Load procedure, add the following code:

```
Dim IEemulation As New InternetExplorerBrowserEmulation
If Not IEemulation.IsBrowserEmulationSet() Then
    IEemulation.SetBrowserEmulationVersion()
End If
```

At program startup, the IE emulation will be made, so that the full CSS capabilities are observed in the Webbrowser control.